# google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, sudo, dependencies

I'm new to Ubuntu. Whenever I try to install anything using `sudo` on my PC, it shows:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
```

I tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

but none of them worked. Please tell me how can I fix this error.

P.S.: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xerial Xenus).

Such as when I try to install VirtualBox:

```
user@User:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
 virtualbox : Depends: virtualbox-dkms (>= 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                       virtualbox-source (>= 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                       virtualbox-modules
              Depends: libgsoap8 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libvncserver1 (>= 0.9.10) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: virtualbox-qt (= 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libqt4-opengl (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I am not able to install anything. Plus, my Chrome is installed and working. However, when I try to install it with `sudo`, this error occurs:

```
~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
```

Comment: do you want to install chrome?

Comment: Please append your question to include the full output of the command that you are using to try and install an application

Comment: Well there are 2 issues. The first is with virtualbox. For that one run `sudo apt-get -f` as the message tells you. If that fails, you need to file a bug report against virtualbox. The second is likely a typo, what is the name of the .deb and why are you not using chromium ?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and try again.

You can't use apt-get install <.deb package>. When you download a .deb package, you must install like windows (double click).

---

You can learn more about apt-get here: https://www.tecmint.com/useful-basic-commands-of-apt-get-and-apt-cache-for-package-management/